# The exception is thrown - and the code is executed further

Tags: java, exception

Faced this with a situation - in the main method, a child method is called, which checks the object, and an exception is thrown in this child method (one of the objects in the list NULL). But the code of the main method still continues to be executed!
Example code:

```
@Transactional
public boolean addCompany(List<Company> companies, List<Address> addresses) throws Exception{
    checkAddress(addresses);
    try{
        for(int i = 0; i < companies.size(); i++){
            if(findCompany(companies.get(i).getId()) == null && !isExistsCompany(companies.get(i))){
                companies.get(i).setAddress(addresses.get(i));
                this.em.persist(companies.get(i));
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void checkAddress(List<Address> addresses) throws Exception{
    try{
        if(addresses == null)
            throw new Exception(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + ": Invalid parameter: list is null");
        for(Address a : addresses)
            if(a == null)
                throw new Exception(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + ": Invalid list item: object is null");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In this regard, several questions arose:
- why the code does not stop?
- Is it now necessary, as an option, to get out of the situation by changing the type of the checkAddress method from void to boolean, and in the main method to process true/false?
- How is correctly handled on the frontend such error - do the text send exceptions to the frontend or just process the code 500 and if so, then why generate an exception on the backend - to help in the development process? How to deal with it competently?
Advise please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you said this is example code, but I feel the need to point out that the whole `getStackTrace()[n]` thing is a bad idea, not only for readability reasons and performance reasons, but also because the JVM is allowed to remove stack frames.  Much better practice is to pass the class name and method name as String arguments, like [certain Logger methods do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#entering-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Without getStackTrace (), how else can I get the name of the current class and method to pass to Logger?

Comment: checkAddress should not be trying to get that information.  Callers should pass them as parameters instead.  Just like the Logger method to which I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void checkAddress(List<Address> addresses) throws Exception{
        if(addresses == null)
            throw new Exception(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + ": Invalid parameter: list is null");
        for(Address a : addresses)
            if(a == null)
                throw new Exception(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName() + "." + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + ": Invalid list item: object is null");
    }

}
```

What is all that stuff about threads?  Crazy code.

Don't allow anyone to add a null instance to the List in the first place.

I might write it this way:

```
public void checkAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
    if (addresses == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Address List cannot be null");
    for (Address a : addresses) {
        if (a == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Address cannot be null");
    }
}
```

Comment: I use getStackTrace () to indicate to myself which package / class / method an error has occurred. The same method is called many times in the code, and in case of an error, you need to quickly find the place where this error occurred. Printing such a stig gives the absolute path to the method with an error.

Comment: You don't need all that noise.  This is an unchecked exception.  I'd advise you to have the caller catch the exception and let you know what happened.  The address method should not be supplying context that way.  It need not know how it was called as I wrote it.

Comment: Understood thanks! And one more question - when did Exception work, that you advise to pass the frontend? By default, the error code 500 is sent, is it worth to pass the exception text, or is it a different tone and it's only necessary to process error 500?

Comment: No, exceptions should never be propagated to a client.  What do they care about your NullPointerException?  It should be translated to a user-friendly message.

Answer (score 2):

You are **catching** the `Exception`(s), when you do not rethrow a `Exception` the Java runtime considers it handled. If you expected program execution to stop then you need the `Exception`(s) to propagate to the caller. For example, in `checkAddress` change

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to something like

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e; // <-- re-throw the Exception
}
```

*or* simply remove the `try` and `catch` altogether, then the `Exception` is automatically thrown to the caller. Also, in Java 8+, you could use a `Stream`. Like,

```
public void checkAddress(List<Address> addresses) throws Exception {
    if (addresses == null) {
        StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(ste[2].getClassName() + "."
                + ste[2].getMethodName() + "." + ste[1].getMethodName()
                + ": Invalid parameter: list is null");
    }
    if (addresses.stream().anyMatch(a -> a == null)) {
        StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(ste[2].getClassName() + "."
                + ste[2].getMethodName() + "." + ste[1].getMethodName()
                + ": Invalid list item: object is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can even do `addresses.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

This line *suppresses* the exception, causing your code to continue rather than fail. It prints the stack trace, which might make it look like the exception is being thrown, but it's not getting any further than that line.

You almost never want to use `printStackTrace()`, you should instead properly handle the exceptions you intend to, or just let the exception propagate to the callers of your method.

Comment: Printing a stack trace is not handling an exception.  If you wanted the method to throw an exception, why do you wrap it in a try/catch block?

Comment: @duffymo I agree with you - that's why I'm discouraging using `printStackTrace()`. I'm not sure what you're objecting to? `.printStackTrace()` is (unfortunately) often auto-added by IDEs when user's try to add a try-catch block as the body of the catch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `try`.. `catch` block from inside `checkAddress()` method. That way, any exception thrown from inside `checkAddress()` are propagate to its caller.

In `addCompany()` method, put call to `checkAddress()` method inside `try` .. `catch` and handle the exception there.

When `checkAddress()` throws exception, code execution will jump to catch block.